# How To Using IF, AND, and VLOOKUP functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help about functions in Excel (`IF`, `AND`, and `Vlookup`)

This is what I made but it's not correct

```
=IF(B4=B4,VLOOKUP(B4,$F$4:$H$9,3,FALSE),"YOUR NAME BOY NOT FOUND")
```

This is image for more my problem information:

[image]

Please Help Me

Thank You

Comment: Can you explain what you’re doing / trying to do (in words)? Which cells are your data and which ones have formula(s)? What is the purpose / objective of the formula? And why in the world are you testing whether ```B4=B4```? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: B4=B4 will always be true.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest you the solution, check the screen shot.

[image]

This Formula you need to use,

{=IFERROR(INDEX(B$9:B$10,SMALL(IF($E$8=A$9:$A$10,ROW(B$9:B$10)-8,""),ROW()-12)),"")}

My **Source Data** Range is  **A9:C10**.

Now in **A13 & A14** write the **Father's name** since it's common.

**Write ADI next to Key Cell in E8**.

In Cell **B13** write the above written Formula and finish it with **Ctrl+Shift+Delete**, after getting the result **drag Formula one Cell Write then one Row down**.

You get the correct mother's name with the child's name too.

**NB:** Remember in the Formula first you find **-8**, reason is **Source data starts from Row 9**. then is **-12** because **Results data starts from Row 13**. *"Be careful about both the parameters otherwise you get wrong Results".*

**Hope this help you I've posted the solution after is been tested by me.**

Comment: please post also a screenshot of your solution, that would help a lot to understand it.

Comment: I'm uploading the screen shot with original answer please check it. Write in case of any problem.

Comment: would be good to have it column and row headers, so we could see address too..

Comment: Read the answer carefully are in Bold Face,,, I've explained every thing.

Comment: I see them, however it's difficult to encode and keep everything in mind.

Comment: Can you help me, for use Function IF, AND, and Vlookup

??

Comment: Bro,,, Check the Screen Shot the Source Data caption is quite visible. Below it  is Father's Name ADI is Cell A9, ANI is in B9 & SUSAN is in C9. KEY CELL is in E7 next is E8 where the Criteria is written. Below Result Caption the Cell is A13. Next to it is B13 here you need to write the FORMULA. Okay,.